# 3d intersections

Tags: pgfplots, intersections

As exercise, I'm trying to draw the intersection of the prism [0,2] x [0,4] x [0,6], and the plane x + y + z = 5.

[image]

My result is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.45cm,-0.385cm)},y={(1cm,-0.1cm)},z={(0,1cm)}]
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node [below left] {$x$};
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,6,0) node [right] {$y$};
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,6) node [right] {$z$};
    
    \filldraw [thick, orange, fill opacity=0.3] (0,0,5) -- (0,4,1) -- (1,4,0) -- (2,3,0) -- (2,0,3) -- cycle;
    \filldraw [thick, blue, fill opacity=0.2] (2,3,0) -- (2,0,3) -- (5,0,0) -- cycle;
    \filldraw [thick, blue, fill opacity=0.2] (1,4,0) -- (0,5,0) -- (0,4,1) -- cycle;
    
    \filldraw [thick, orange, fill opacity=0.3] (2,3,0) -- (2,0,0) -- (2,0,3) -- cycle;
    \filldraw [thick, orange, fill opacity=0.3] (1,4,0) -- (0,4,0) -- (0,4,1) --cycle;
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have some questions now:

- I think there's a lot of code just to represent an easy mathematical volume as [0,2] x [0,4] x [0,6]. Is there some more efficient way of drawing it?
- Do I need to calculate the intersections by hand and then represent it? Or is there any direct method?
- How can I obtain the same result by using an `axis` environment and `\addplot` commands instead of `\draw`? I've tried but I'm new to `\addplot3` and I'm having trouble with axis position (`view={}{}`), `colormap` has not a homogeneus color, the surface has a grid that difficults the understanding of the picture and I have the same doubt on intersections, Do I need to calculate them by hand?

Full prism is:

```
\draw [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.3] (0,0,6) -- (2,0,6) -- (2,4,6) -- (0,4,6) -- cycle ;
\draw [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.3] (2,0,0) -- (2,0,6) -- (2,4,6) -- (2,4,0) -- cycle ;
\draw [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.3] (2,4,0) -- (0,4,0) -- (0,4,6) -- (2,4,6) -- cycle ;
```

Comment: For pgfplots, the [axis equal] and [axis lines=center] might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what you do, consider installing a 3d view in a more systematic way. The perhaps best way to get this is to use `asymptote`, which does have tools to compute intersections in 3d. If you want to use `pgfplots`, use `patch plots`. However, for this you need to still compute the intersections yourself. This post is to mention some [experimental Ti*k*Z library](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools) which also allows one to compute intersections in 3d.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}%https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background} 
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{behind}  
\pgfsetlayers{behind,background,main,foreground}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
    3d/install view={theta=70,phi=110},
    line cap=round,line join=round,
    visible/.style={draw,thick,solid},
    hidden/.style={draw,very thin,cheating dash},
    3d/polyhedron/.cd,fore/.style={visible,fill opacity=0.6},
    back/.style={fill opacity=0.6,hidden,3d/polyhedron/complete dashes},
    fore layer=foreground,
    back layer=background
    ]
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (6,0,0) coordinate (ex) node [below left] {$x$};
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,6,0) coordinate (ey) node [right] {$y$};
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,6) coordinate (ez) node [right] {$z$};
  \path (5,0,0) coordinate (A) (0,5,0) coordinate (B) (0,0,5) coordinate (C)
   (2.5,0,0) coordinate (a) (0,3.5,0) coordinate (b) (0,0,2) coordinate (c) ;
  \path[3d/.cd,plane with normal={(ex) through (a) named px},
      plane with normal={(ey) through (b) named py},
      line through={(A) and (B) named lAB},
      line through={(A) and (C) named lAC},
      line through={(B) and (C) named lBC}];
  \path[3d/intersection of={lAB with px}] coordinate (pABx)
   [3d/intersection of={lAB with py}] coordinate (pABy)
   [3d/intersection of={lAC with px}] coordinate (pACx)
   [3d/intersection of={lBC with py}] coordinate (pBCy);
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybarycenterA}{barycenter("(A),(pABx),(pACx),(a)")} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybarycenterB}{barycenter("(B),(pABy),(pBCy),(b)")} 
  \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,O={(\mybarycenterA)},color=blue,
      draw face with corners={{(A)},{(pABx)},{(pACx)}},
      draw face with corners={{(A)},{(pABx)},{(a)}},
      draw face with corners={{(A)},{(a)},{(pACx)}},
      O={(\mybarycenterB)},
      draw face with corners={{(B)},{(pABy)},{(pBCy)}},
      draw face with corners={{(B)},{(pABy)},{(b)}},
      draw face with corners={{(B)},{(b)},{(pBCy)}},
      color=orange,O={(1,1,1)},
      draw face with corners={{(pABx)},{(pACx)},{(C)},{(pBCy)},{(pABy)}},
      draw face with corners={{(a)},{(pACx)},{(C)},{(O)}},
      draw face with corners={{(b)},{(pBCy)},{(C)},{(O)}},
      draw face with corners={{(b)},{(pABy)},{(pABx)},{(a)},{(O)}}
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Still a lot of efforts. However, there is one benefit: you can change the view and still get the correct result. E.g. for `3d/install view={theta=70,phi=60},` you'll get

[image]

Of course, this is also true for `asymptote` and `patch plot` solutions (perhaps except for the possibility to automatically have the hidden lines dashed).

Comment: As you said, this is still a lot of effort, and I can obtain your rotated figure just changing `x={(1cm,-0.4cm)},y={(1cm,0.25cm)},z={(0,1cm)}` in my code and adding `\filldraw [thick, orange, fill opacity=0.3] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) -- (2,0,3) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;
    \filldraw [thick, blue, fill opacity=0.2] (2,0,3) -- (2,0,0) -- (5,0,0) -- cycle;` so it isn't a great benefit. By the way, your answer doesn't solve the 3 doubts I asked in my question

Comment: @Á.Iborra I beg to disagree. In your code one has to order the faces by hand. If you change the view enough, the result will no longer be correct without manual reordering of the `\filldraw` commands. Also the answer does address how to do things in an axis: `patch plots`.